# How to stop service started by another fragment of the same activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service

I have two fragments `AlertTabFragment` and `WalkAloneTabFragment`.
I have started a Service called `LocationService` from `AlertTabFragment` but I am unable to stop the `LocationService` from `WalkAloneTabFragment`.

The `LocationService` is a bit resource occupying since it has `LocationListener` and `GpsListener`. Since the `LocationService` is used for speedometer functionality with an alert system and it also updates the current location through a `webservice` and on top of that it has the functionality of `GpsListener`.

So whenever I am trying to call a `webservice` from `WalkAloneTabFragment` it is taking time so I want to stop the service whenever I call it and after that, I will again start the service, so that it does not allocate so much resources.

**AlertTabFragment.java**

```
public class AlertTabFragment extends Fragment
{

    private final String TAG = AlertTabFragment.class.getName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alert, container, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside onCreateView");
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), LocationService.class);
        getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside onResume");
        super.onResume();

        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(HomeScreenActivity.mBroadcastAlertAction))
                {
                    // Code Related to Locaton Listener of LocationService.java
                }
                else if (intent.getAction().equals(HomeScreenActivity.mBroadcastAlertGpsAction))
                {
                    // Code Related Gps Listener of LocationService.java
                }

            }
        };
        IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(HomeScreenActivity.mBroadcastAlertAction);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(HomeScreenActivity.mBroadcastAlertGpsAction);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(HomeScreenActivity.mBroadcastWalkAloneAction);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside onDestroy");
    }

}
```

Comment: If your intention is to start the `Service`  again after a small interval of time, you should consider pausing the operation since, stopping and restarting the `Service` may get costly.

Comment: @Shaishav Actually I have to run the `Service` for the lifetime of the app, but since its causing problem when calling I am calling a `webservice` from `WalkAloneTabFragment`, so I have no other option than stopping and starting Service at least that way the `webservice` will be called without any delay.

Comment: At WalkAloneTabFragment Fragment you can send a broadcast by the sendBroadCast(intent) method with intent add action that mReceiver at AlertTabFragment fragment can receive. At the onReceive() method you can stopService(intent) with intent that you define to startService(intent).

Comment: So basically if you wanna stop the service from someplace with in the same process, I would send a command using `startService(Intent)` perhaps with an added flag to check whether the service is already running before sending the command, and handle command received from the service and call `stopSelf()` or anything for that matter.

Comment: Hope you have tried this already from your WalkAloneTabFragment  Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),AppLocationService.class); stopService(intent);